# Assertion Error in OVSSwitch.open() : Unable to connect switches to controller

Tags: docker, mininet, openvswitch, ryu

I am getting the Assertion error while trying to deploy a topology.
As you can see from the logs that hosts and switches are deployed but the controller is giving trouble.

I am uploading the logs:

```
rishabh@rishabh-VirtualBox:~/VNF_DockerNet/mininet_script/DockerTopo$ sudo python topo-clos-like.py
[sudo] password for rishabh:
/home/rishabh/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/__init__.py:83: RequestsDependencyWarning: Old version of cryptography ([1, 2, 3]) may cause slowdown.
  warnings.warn(warning, RequestsDependencyWarning)
*** CONTROL PLANE STARTS
*** Add Remote Controller for debugging
Unable to contact the remote controller at 182.26.0.1:6600
*** DATA PLANE STARTS
*** Add spine switches
s.spine1: kwargs {'listenPort': None, 'protocols': 'OpenFlow10,OpenFlow11,OpenFlow12,OpenFlow13', 'volumes': ['/home/mininet/GIT/VNF_DockerNet/Docker/Shared:/Shared:rw', '/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:rw', '/dev:/dev:rw', '/lib/modules:/lib/modules:rw'], 'inNamespace': False}
s.spine1: update resources {'cpu_quota': -1}
*** Add leaf/rack switches
s.rack2: kwargs {'listenPort': None, 'protocols': 'OpenFlow10,OpenFlow11,OpenFlow12,OpenFlow13', 'volumes': ['/home/mininet/GIT/VNF_DockerNet/Docker/Shared:/Shared:rw', '/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:rw', '/dev:/dev:rw', '/lib/modules:/lib/modules:rw'], 'inNamespace': False}
s.rack2: update resources {'cpu_quota': -1}
s.rack3: kwargs {'listenPort': None, 'protocols': 'OpenFlow10,OpenFlow11,OpenFlow12,OpenFlow13', 'volumes': ['/home/mininet/GIT/VNF_DockerNet/Docker/Shared:/Shared:rw', '/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:rw', '/dev:/dev:rw', '/lib/modules:/lib/modules:rw'], 'inNamespace': False}
s.rack3: update resources {'cpu_quota': -1}
*** Add inter-switch links
*** Create hosts and links between host and switchs
h1: kwargs {'ip': '11.0.0.1/24'}
h1: update resources {'cpu_quota': -1}
h2: kwargs {'ip': '11.0.0.2/24'}
h2: update resources {'cpu_quota': -1}
h3: kwargs {'ip': '11.0.0.3/24'}
h3: update resources {'cpu_quota': -1}
h4: kwargs {'ip': '11.0.0.4/24'}
h4: update resources {'cpu_quota': -1}
*** All devices are deployed
v1: kwargs {'ip': '11.0.0.5/24'}
v1: update resources {'cpu_quota': -1}
v2: kwargs {'ip': '11.0.0.6/24'}
v2: update resources {'cpu_quota': -1}
v3: kwargs {'ip': '11.0.0.7/24'}
v3: update resources {'cpu_quota': -1}
v4: kwargs {'ip': '11.0.0.8/24'}
v4: update resources {'cpu_quota': -1}
*** Configuring hosts
h1 h2 h3 h4 v1 v2 v3 v4
*** Add all switches to first available controller
Shell unblocked after 120.00sTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "topo-clos-like.py", line 45, in <module>
    net=clos.startNetwork(REST=False)
  File "/home/rishabh/VNF_DockerNet/mininet_script/DockerTopo/ClosTree.py", line 149, in startNetwork
    sw.start([self.c0]) if(self.c0) else sw.start()
  File "/home/rishabh/VNF_DockerNet/mininet_script/DockerTopo/DockerNodes.py", line 87, in start
    OVSSwitch.start(self,[])
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/mininet/node.py", line 1767, in start
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/mininet/node.py", line 1655, in vsctl
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/mininet/node.py", line 991, in cmd
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/mininet/node.py", line 973, in sendCmd
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/mininet/node.py", line 310, in sendCmd
AssertionError
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Can you show us what you are doing? Maybe also add some tests like ping the ryu machine from the ovs machine?

Comment: Thanks for your help actually i had to change the nodes.py in mininet for my project.